How to blur an input field using Testing Library UserEvent?
How can I blur an input field using @testing-library/user-event? I know there's fireEvent.blur, but is there an alternative with userEvent?

You can emulate the Tab keypress to blur the currently focused input field. For example:
const input = await screen.findByLabelText(/username/i)

await userEvent.type(username, 'johndoe[Tab]')

This will type johndoe in the input field and then hit the Tab button, making the field lose focus.
